# Force npm download from private registry

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

In my nodejs project I had to modify 4 of the node modules and upload them to our private corporate registry so the project will download the modified versions during builds.  I did this by changing the `resolved` field in `package-lock.json` for each dependency from our virtual npm registry which forwards downloads to the public npm registry to our private registry.

This is working for 3 out of the 4 modules, however 1 module, `phantomjs-prebuilt`,  will not download the one I uploaded.  When I view its package.json after installing, its `_resolved` field shows the correct private registry I entered in `package-lock.json`, but the module doesn't have my modifications.

If I create a test project with a `package.json` that has `phantomjs-prebuilt` as its only dependency and modify the lock file to download from the private registry it will download the correct modified version I uploaded.  I'm assuming there must be some transitive dependency overriding it, but I thought I would be able to see that from the lock file and override it.  `phantomjs-prebuilt` only appears once in my lock file and that's where I'm making the change to the `resolved` field.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue myself, recently. This may not help you in particular if releasing as a different version is not an option, but maybe others who stumble across this answer like I did.

What I did was to release a forked version of a package, under a new version.

So, I forked moddle-xml 10.0.0, and released a package 10.0.1337 into our private registry in Artifactory.

That way, I could replace the transitive package dependencies of a package that we used with the forked version 10.0.1337 (using [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions)), not breaking any constraints like `^10.0.0`.
EDIT: If you want to replace a particular outside version, I think you can work with exclusion / inclusion filters.

The Artifactory-based registry would then offer a single virtual registry containing both the npm-local packages (including my fork) and npm-remote packages (the normal stuff from the default registry) [setup guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#npmRegistry-Overview).
I would configure my local setup to only download from that virtual registry.

The Artifactory setup comes with a few pitfalls (like, you have to give read permissions to all physical repositories (npm-local AND npm-remote), not just the virtual one, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960455/npm-error-403-when-downloading-dependencies-from-jfrog-artifactory/71022149#71022149)), but it works fine for me now.

(I'm sure something like this is possible with other than the Artifactory implementation, this particular thing is just the stuff I know)