# How force the download of npm modules located in private nexus npm registry instead local modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus, package.json, npm-registry

## Scenario

I have a configured nexus repository working as npm registry with **redeploy** enabled. I know that enable redeploy is a bad practice, but we are in stabilization stage.

## Problem

When I try to install my private module into local nodejs project, I always get the previous version:

```
npm install acme-module --save
```

## Validations

- I deleted the folder in nexus repository and perform a new **npm publish** without any errors.
- I can see the new folder, with correct .tgz and if I download it (right click and save) I can see my latest version of source code, which is good.
- I tried to [uninstall all npm modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally), but always the previous version is downloaded.

## Possible cause

If I disconnect from the internet, **npm install** is still working without any error. So I guess, my npm private module **acme-module**, is **cached** in some folder, and this prevent the download of latest version.

## Question

Why **npm install** works without internet connection and how **force** the download of exact versions, located in my nexus registry instead local modules.

## Similar questions

- [Force npm download from private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752069/force-npm-download-from-private-registry)  (without response :S)

Comment: Did you delete your local machines npm cache?  Mine is located at $HOME/.npm.  Or is your question how to bypass that local cache?

Comment: I will try with $HOME/.npm.  I tried uninstalling nodejs and works but was just a test. Yes, it will be great to bypass the local cache justo for development purposes like -snapshot sufixes in maven + java

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to bypass the local cache (if possible), I just delete mine if I am experiecing any concerns I think may be cache related to be sure.